# Regular expression to parse a specific URL segment

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get a string from a URL in C#.  The URL will look something like this:

http://www.somesite.com/something/I-WANT-THIS-SEGMENT/cms/somethingelse

OR

http://www.somesite.com/something/someotherthing/I-WANT-THIS-SEGMENT/cms

OR

http://www.somesite.com/I-WANT-THIS-SEGMENT/cms/something

Basically, I want the segment before the "cms"

Comment: Before `/cms` until the next `/` backwards?

Comment: Look at the URI class in C#, and read the documentation from that on MSDN.

Comment: Wait a minute...What just happened here?  The question was closed without an answer.  And, it was deemed not to be a real question?  How is that possible?  I need the segment preceding the "cms" segment which may occur anywhere within the url.

Comment: @Paul For the most part, we're not here to do your work for you. You had a problem, but you showed us no effort.  That behavior is usually considered toxic by the community (hence the downvotes).  We expect you to put some effort into your problem. What have you tried? What didn't work? What code do you have to show us?

Comment: You asked me what I had tried, then like minutes later, you closed the question without giving me a chance to respond.  Not fair.

Comment: @Paul Even with your question closed, you can edit it. The point is to edit it into shape and then flag it (or vote) to reopen it. Flagging it would be faster since a moderator closed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so pretty, but I think that you don't need a regex here:

```
string Url1 = @"http://www.somesite.com/something/I-WANT-THIS-SEGMENT/cms/somethingelse";
string Url2 = @"http://www.somesite.com/something/someotherthing/I-WANT-THIS-SEGMENT/cms";
string Url3 = @"http://www.somesite.com/I-WANT-THIS-SEGMENT/cms/something";

Url1 = Url1.Substring(0, Url1.IndexOf("/cms"));
string PartOfUrl1 = Url1.Substring(Url1.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
Console.WriteLine(PartOfUrl1);

Url2 = Url2.Substring(0, Url2.IndexOf("/cms"));
string PartOfUrl2 = Url2.Substring(Url2.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
Console.WriteLine(PartOfUrl2);

Url3 = Url3.Substring(0, Url3.IndexOf("/cms"));
string PartOfUrl3 = Url3.Substring(Url3.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
Console.WriteLine(PartOfUrl3);
```

Using the `Uri` class would be nice too, as George pointed out.

Comment: Thanks...I was trying to do it without substring, but I guess that is probably the easiest.